# MsalServiceException when using AcquireTokenInteractive. AADSTS80014: Validation request responded after maximum elapsed time exceeded

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

I have a Xamarin Forms iOS app that uses MSAL (Microsoft.Identity.Client) to acquire access tokens.

```
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AppSettings.ClientId)
          .WithTenantId(AppSettings.TenantId)
          .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.microsoft.adalcache")
          .WithRedirectUri($"msal{AppSettings.ClientId}://auth")
          .Build();

var authResult = await this.app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                  .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.CurrentActivityOrWindow)
                  .ExecuteAsync();
```

This code works fine on Android, but on iOS, after I enter my username and password, an `MsalUiRequiredException` is thrown. I have two factor enabled on my Microsoft Work or School account, and the exception seems to be thrown before the second part of the login.

```
AADSTS80014: Validation request responded after maximum elapsed time exceeded.
```

The Exception details seem to indicate that a timeout has occurred, so I tried using a custom `HttpClientFactory` with an increased timeout, but the Exception is still thrown at the same spot.

The `OpenUrl` override in my `AppDelegate` does not get called.

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
{
    // Never get here
    AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(url);
    return base.OpenUrl(app, url, options);
}
```

I have configured the callback scheme in my `Info.plist`

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>{bundle Id}</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>msal{clientId}</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

And enabled keychain access in `Entitlements.plist`

```
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.microsoft.adalcache</string>
    </array>
 </dict>
```

I am pretty sure the Azure side of things is configured correctly because it is working on Android. Is there something else on iOS that I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer isn't likely to apply to anyone else, but the issue was caused by our AD Sync server being offline.

Existing Access tokens were working, but I could not obtain any new ones.